# God will never give you a cross that you cannot carry

Tags: scripture, krishna, philosophy, bhagavad-gita

Many times I have heard from Christian people this saying, when you are going through a difficult situation (that is your cross) and that God would never give you a cross that you would not be able to carry.
So you should have faith and patience and acceptance of the will of God, and ... surrender to Him (as Arjuna did in the Bhagavad Gita).

I wonder if there would be a similar analogy in the Vedic scriptures.

One thing that comes to my mind is the battle of Kurukshetra. Krishna took Arjuna to the front of the opposing army so that he could see those he would shortly face in battle.

so question is:
how I would `translate` the cross saying into something from the Vedas?

Comment: The problem with your question is that the Christian saying you allude to puts the blame on God for what happens to you in your life. In Hinduism, God is not responsible; you are responsible for the karma that you suffer or enjoy. God is not responsible, you alone are responsible. There are many passages in the Gita that say that a person who becomes unattached to his actions or offers them up to God, becomes free; liberated. But cross implies a priori that you are not responsible for what befalls you.

Comment: that's absolutely right, still Paramatma `allowed` it to happen in a certain way. Of course there is no question about that, we're the ones responsible, as we reap what we sow.